# How to fill the inside of an SCNBox

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I'm experimenting with SceneKit and trying to make a labyrinth style of game with it. However, one of the issues is that when you have moved inside a box (tube, sphere etc), the projection of the box disappears.

I've gone through the documentation multiple times and I either not matching the right wording or it's not in there.

How would you fill the contents of a box so that when you move through it you will be in the dark?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

An `SCNMaterial` has an `isDoubleSided` property which is:

> A Boolean value that determines whether SceneKit should render both
>   front and back faces of a surface.

By default this is set to `false` meaning that your contents will only be displayed on one side e.g. the outside.

> If you change this property’s value to YES, SceneKit renders both the
>   front and back surfaces of every polygon.

As such and example of rendering on both sides can be achieved like so:

```
func createBoxNode(){

    //1. Create An SCNNode With An SCNBox Geometry
    let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0))

    //2. Set The Colour Of All Sides To Cyan
    boxNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan

    //3. Enusre That Both Sides Are Rendered
    boxNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true

    //4. Place Our BoxNode & Add It To The Hierachy
    boxNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1.5)
    self.augmentedRealityView?.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I didn't expect it to be a material property instead of a SCNBox or SCNNode property. Thank you very much!

Comment: :) Please mark as the correct answer so this can be closed :)